# How to add HTML to drupal 7 module?

Tags: html, image, drupal, module, drupal-7

I am making a module which takes user input, validates it and displays a picture based on user input. Here is my code:

```
<?php

function fisheye_menu()
{
    $items                          = array();
    $items['examples/form-example'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
        'title' => 'Fisheye fotografie', //page title
        'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
        'page arguments' => array(
            'fisheye_form'
        ), //put the name of the form here
        'access callback' => TRUE
    );
    return $items;
}
;

function fisheye_form($form, &$form_state)
{

    $form['datetime'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Vyberte dátum a čas'),
        '#required' => TRUE
    );

    $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
        drupal_get_path('module', 'fisheye') . '/3rdparty/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js',
        drupal_get_path('module', 'fisheye') . '/3rdparty/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon-master/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js'
    );

    $form['#attached']['css'] = array(
        drupal_get_path('module', 'fisheye') . '/3rdparty/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css',
        drupal_get_path('module', 'fisheye') . '/3rdparty/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon-master/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css'
    );

    drupal_add_js('
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $("#edit-datetime").datetimepicker({
                 dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
             });
      });', 'inline');

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit'
    );
    return $form;
}
;

function fisheye_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    $dateTimeString = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $form_state['values']['datetime']);
    $day            = substr($dateTimeString, 0, 2);
    $month          = substr($dateTimeString, 2, 2);
    $year           = substr($dateTimeString, 4, 4);
    $hour           = substr($dateTimeString, 8, 2);
    $minute         = substr($dateTimeString, 10, 12);
    $dir            = "/meteo_data/IMStestMF/ImagesCameraFisheye/$year/$month/$day";
    $files          = file_scan_directory($dir, '/.*?/');
    drupal_set_message($dateTimeString);
}
;

?>
```

So I need a way to display the image after the form has been submitted. I could use HTML which would create  tags with proper src (or if there is any better way, ill use it), but since I am just a beginner when it comes to drupal, I feel really lost here and I really don't know how to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to a callback where you can take all the parameters you want and display the image based on the parameters.

In your submit handler use drupal_goto('your_callback/$year/$month/$day');

and then in the callback you can print image by using theme hook of your module.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I figured it out already. 

I am using a form with ajax submit handler to call my function which injects html into my placeholder (which is suffix in my form).